# Not able to install socketIO-client

Tags: python, websocket, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to enable communication through WebSocket. For this, I am using socketIO-client. I am in virtual environment 'virtualenv' and I am using the command `pip install -U socketIO-client==0.7.2` in terminal, but I am seeing this error.

```
(.virtualenv)pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install -U socketIO-client==0.7.2
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement socketIO-client==0.7.2 in ./.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking socketIO-client==0.7.2
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for socketIO-client==0.7.2 in ./.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

What should I do to install socketIO-client?

PS: I have also tried `pip install -U socketIO-client`, it shows the same error.
I was following this [link](https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client/)

Comment: Upgrade your `pip` first: `pip install -U pip`, then try again.

Comment: @AKX it is give this result. 

`Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x75f81990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pip/

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: That looks like your machine doesn't have a proper Internet connection, as it can't resolve the name.

Comment: @AKX I am using raspberry pi 3 and I don't think there is a problem with internet, I am able to access internet on web browser in it.
what could be the other possibility?